# Requesting someone to ask a question of another person

Tags: inversion, register, imperative-sentences

Which one would be correct, please

> a) Just ask him if he has received the payment
>   b) Just ask him has he received the payment
>   c) Just ask him whether he has received the payment

Comment: B) is a wrong. Just ask him IF or WHETHER he has received payment.

Comment: yes, that's what I have concluded myself. In my opinion, the most suitable option would be WHETHER. IF could've been used IN THIS PARTICULAR example too.

Comment: In general, please provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please). For example, where you found this or why you want to know. If this is for an essay or an exam, then a) is probably the right choice. However, in causal or informal writing or speech, b) is used too.

Comment: b) makes me think of an uneducated speaker. I do not criticize how people speak as a linguist. But, if wearing a teacher hat, I would not teach this as an acceptable standard English form. So, if ya wanna go street, yeah, its good. If not, it ain't.

Comment: Your question would be improved if you can tell us more what you mean by "correct". Answers can be more specific if you explain why you want to know. Do you have a certain situation in mind, in which the message would be used? In conversation, to answer a question on a test or quiz? In a certain country or culture? In an office? Is the speaker intending to be polite and helpful, or is the speaker angry or impatient? In a novel, representing something a street criminal might say to one of their gang members?

Comment: Don't you think the first sentence is ambiguous (  considered as a reported sentence and a conditional with the imperative) ?

Comment: @V.V. Technically, it could be read as a conditional, with the expected comma, but that would be unlikely--unless what he's to be asked is established by context--because native speakers would almost certainly style such as *If he's been paid, just ask him [if/for something].*

Comment: FWIW, @JimReynolds and everyone, besides direct speech and indirect speech (which are routinely taught in English classes as if that's all there is), we also have free indirect speech, which may explain why many speakers, uneducated or well-educated, use (b) in their spontaneous speech sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English speakers use both of them.

The second one would be expected only in casual speech and written representations of speech. If it were written, including the comma, as in kasfme's answer, would be more conventional and more acceptable to some people.

Comment: B) is wrong. It is not grammatical at all.

Comment: Although B is not grammatical, it is used by English speakers. Jim Reynolds implies this when they say that it is used in _casual_ speech, and _very informal_ writing. But I suppose Lambie is correct. As written, B is not considered correct in formal written contexts.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask about formal discourse. *Correctness* is a meaningless term unless it is defined such that speakers and listeners share an understanding of it. So is *ungrammatical,* as there are many grammars. Some grammars aspire higher than others to define terms such as *grammatical.* I am relatively ignorant in this area myself, but I know enough to understand that labeling B in the question as merely *incorrect, ungrammatical, unacceptable,* etc., is folly, tending to create more confusion in any learner than it resolves.

Answer (score 5):

> a) Just ask him if he has received the payment
>
> b) Just ask him has he received the payment
>
> c) Just ask him whether he has received the payment

As extensively stated in other answers, all three are to some extent "correct".  A and C are more "standard" (written or spoken) responses while B is a more colloquial spoken response.

Focusing specifically on B: It seems like a transformation of a direct quote into an indirect quote:

> Ask him, "Have you received the payment?"
>
> Ask him has he received the payment.

In spoken English it's not common to *directly* quote, word-for-word, what someone says or should say to someone else.  The more natural way to express this is to transform the quote to the third-person and (implicitly) remove the quotations marks.  Naturally you need to transform all the other pronouns to match the subject:

> Could you ask him, "Did you receive the present I sent you on your birthday?"
>
> Could you ask him did he receive the present I sent him on his birthday.

This would not be common in *written* English unless the author was writing dialogue.  Also while not always written, there is still an implied comma after "him".

It's possible this is just a simple extension of other uses of the indirect quote:

> The newspaper says, "He is going to be the next mayor"
>
> The newspaper says he is going to be the next mayor.

.

> The caller said, "I think you should vote for him to be the next mayor".
>
> The caller said he thinks I should vote for him to be the next mayor.

.

> The candidate for mayor said, "I'm going to clean up this town!"
>
> The candidate for mayor said he is going to clean up this town.

Again in the same way,

> Could I ask, "Is he the right person for the job?"
>
> Could I ask is he the right person for the job?

This pattern still sounds strange to my ears.  I would say:

> Could I ask if he is the right person for the job?

but it might be common in another vernacular.  The best way to get familiar with these colloquialisms is to listen extensively to people who speak that vernacular.

Comment: I think the key question here is whether B (especially if it includes the much-demanded comma!) is informal Standard English, ungrammatical in Standard English, or ungrammatical in Standard English but grammatical in some dialects or in some *particular* "standard English", of which there are several. The authors of *The Cambridge Grammer of the English Language,* widely considered by linguists to be the best general and comprehensive grammar available, discuss this issue here: http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam033/2001025630.pdf.

Comment: My interest in the question springs from my not knowing the best answer myself, and because my current state of learning is focused on this kind of issue, not to put down people who might only know what I knew a few months ago. With reference to your designation of *colloquial,* see especially section 2.2(b), last paragraph. The authors themselves acknowledge that defining "Standard English" is a "subtle concept". And certainly some intelligent experts have different perspectives. But the best answers will provide support for our opinions.

Comment: Essentially, we need a meaningful definition of the term *correct,* if we are to designate an utterance as being correct or incorrect.

Comment: I think you are on to something when you notice similarities between B and the grammar of *indirect speech,* but it is also different from the most typical examples of indirect speech that I'm familiar with. If B is an example of indirect speech, or If the grammatical logic for B rationally extends from that of reported speech so tightly that its reasonably deemed grammatical informal discourse, I'd like to see more detail on that.

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with your statement that B sounds strange to your ears, but we often feel strange about language that we deliberately focus on, when--if someone just said that to us in everyday life--we would process the meaning without thought and perhaps experience it as perfectly natural. Maybe this idea can be illustrated to some extent by looking at something like *How do you do?* Lots of English is strange!

Comment: @JimReynolds I'm not a linguist so this is my best guess toward an explanation.  The pattern feels more natural if I insert a pause between the first and second parts of the sentence, "Can I ask, is he the right person for the job?" similar to the way someone might say it in conversation.  This mirrors the way you would write a quote without the marks, which is why I call it an "indirect quote".  There may be a more official name for the structure.

Comment: Also, I don't know if there is any official line that defines what is and isn't a "colloquialism".  I do know there are many speech patterns common to Southern California (and those who emulate the culture), and it only seems reasonable to call them colloquialisms because they are used in casual speech and don't appear in written speech except as dialogue.  In the same way this pattern doesn't seem common in written speech, but could show up in dialogue.

Comment: I agree with the votes. This is the best answer so far. I had thought that indirect speech only reported on the past, but it makes sense that it can refer to a current or future, or hypothetical utterance: *She'll say she's not gonna go.* I had also not heard of *free indirect speech* that @Damkerng T mentions in a comment to the question, though I don't think B is an example of it.

Answer (score -1):

A is correct.

a) is an instruction. Just ask him.

b) should be written as question. When speaking, you can use b) like this:

Just ask him, has he received the payment?

Comment: They are both imperatives. Neither is a statement. http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/impersent09.htm

Comment: I did not realise that statements and imperatives were mutually exclusive. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

Note that in your first example, the word "if" is not used to introduce a conditional clause, but to mean "whether". The two words are often interchangeable, depending on the context, but not always.

For instance, the following examples have different meanings:
"Let me know if you are going" and "let me know whether you are going".

In the first example the request is to be informed IF "you are going" (but not if you are not going).

In the second example, the request is to be informed of your intention, whether or not you are going.

http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/if_and_whether.htm

Answer (score -1):

Basic Grammar:

a) Just ask him if he has received the payment [correct]

b) Just ask him has he received the payment [incorrect]

BEST:
c) Just ask  him whether he received the payment or has received the payment. [correct, both verb forms]

Comment: This is merely a statement that a sentence is "incorrect", apparently meaning ungrammatical. Based on what evidence? It seems to me that you are confusing formality with grammaticality. English speakers use language like this, especially in speech, especially informally. Who can say that it's "incorrect"?

Comment: There is a minimum acceptable level: /Just ask him: "Has he received the payment?"/ But not as formulated under B above. I guess you have never taught English. I mean let's just say whatever right? Or does any go? I am not confusing anything with anything. It is best not to teach trailer park forms to English language learners. They'll get their soon enough. It's spoken English for sure, uneducated register.

Comment: Again, you merely state that there is a minimum acceptable level (of what?) You are engaging in what is called *taste tyranny* in chapter 1 of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language,* widely considered to be the best general description of the grammar of the language by linguists. It is available here: http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam033/2001025630.pdf. The widespread problem of imposing one's personal preferences and opinions on others as "rules" is described therein. I do not doubt that your intention is positive and that you have contributions to make.

Comment: If a piece of discourse is, let us suppose, used only by people who live in trailer parks, should they be prohibited from speaking? What if an author wants to write a novel populated with characters who live in trailer parks? If such an author wrote representations of their speech, would all such writing be "incorrect"? Who has the authority to decide that, besides you?

Comment: I said, and now **repeat** that as a linguist, all speech is legitimate, fine and wonderful. No one has an RIGHT to criticize an individual's speech in terms of anything at all. That said, when one is answering questions from learners, one doesn't go round saying that what a linguist would consider marked as informal, spoken and non-standard speech is grammatically correct re the canon (not set by me, I would add). Any school, university or other "institution, etc. (press, media etc.) would say the same. Of course, in literature, everything is possible.

Comment: Yes, I am answering questions here from English language learners, ergo, I point out what is considered to be grammatically correct in terms of teaching someone to speak or write English. Not by me but by the larger community. This is not about "the tyranny of style"(as it is not a style questionj!); it is about saying There's apples on the table versus There're apples on the table. One doesn't want learners to not realize the kind of speech they are using. Would you teach someone: There's apples on the table? Or explain to them why people say it??

Answer (score -1):

Your option a is already correct. The key word there is "if." It sets up a conditional phrase and expects back a simple true or false.

Your option b is incomplete. You could phrase it this way instead:

```
Just ask him, "have you received the payment".
```

but that's a different type of statement. In my formatting you're specifically telling someone what words to say rather providing more generic instructions.

Your option c is arguably incomplete. The key word here is "whether." The word "whether" is different from the word "if" in that it sets up an either or phrase. So a more correct (or rather more formal) variant would be:

```
Just ask him whether or not he received the payment.
```

You don't have to use the "or not" phrasing, but it is the more complete way to write that sentence.

Comment: Option B is "incomplete" according to who? Your answer would be improved if you provided evidence to support your statements.